# Where's wrong in my reasoning behind upper bound for reconstruction error?

Tags: autoencoders, mutual-information, gan

In the paper [Mutual Information Neural Estimation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04062), the authors derive the reconstruction error in BiGAN as 
$$
\mathcal R=E_{x\sim q(x)}E_{z\sim q(z|x)}\left[-\log p(x|z)\right]
$$
where $q(z|x)$ is the encoder and $p(x|z)$ is the generator/decoder. Here's the derivation I derive following the paper

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal R&=E_{x\sim q(x)}E_{z\sim q(z|x)}\left[-\log p(x|z)\right]\\
&=E_{x,z\sim q(x,z)}\left[\log {p(z)\over p(x, z)}\right]\\
&=E_{x,z\sim q(x, z)}\left[\log {q(x,z)\over p(x,z)}-\log q(x,z)+\log p(z) \right]\\
&=D_{KL}(q(x,z)\Vert p(x,z))+H_q(x,z)+ E_{z\sim q}\left[\log p(z)\right]\\
&=D_{KL}(q(x,z)\Vert p(x,z))+H_q(x,z)-D_{KL}(q(z)\Vert p(z))-H_q(z)\\
&=D_{KL}(q(x,z)\Vert p(x,z))-D_{KL}(q(z)\Vert p(z))+H_q(x|z)\\
&=D_{KL}(q(x,z)\Vert p(x,z))-D_{KL}(q(z)\Vert p(z))-I_q(x,z)+H_q(x)\\
&\le D_{KL}(q(x,z)\Vert p(x,z))-I_q(x,z)+H_q(x)
\end{align}
$$

There're two things confusing me:

1. I think $H_q(x,z)-H_q(z)=H_q(x|z)$, but the authors wrote $H_q(x,z)-H_q(z):=H_q(z|x)$. I searched $:=$ and found that this symbol means "is defined to be". Why are $H_q(x,z)-H_q(z)$ defined to be $H_q(z|x)$?
2. In the above derivation or in the proof from the paper, $q$ concerns the encoder and $p$ the generator. However, in section 5.2 of the paper, $q$ represents the generator and $p$ the encoder. The mystery is that both use $I_q$ in the upper bound. I can make sense of the reconstruction error if $q$ is the encoder, but not the generator. However, assuming $q$ is associated with the encoder and $p$ the generator, I think maximizing the mutual information $I_p(x,y)$ is more intuitive than maximizing $I_q(x,z)$ since we want to have a better generator rather an encoder. So I now don't know which one is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is a general fact from information theory. In the continuous case, the conditional (differential) entropy can be rewritten via:
   \begin{align}
   \mathbb{H}[Z|X] &= \mathbb{E}_x\left[ \mathbb{H}[Z|X=x] \right] \\
   &= \int \mathbb{H}[Z|X=x] \,dx \\ 
   &= \int\left[-\int p(z|x) \log p(z|x) \,dz\right] p(x) \,dx \\ 
   &= -\iint p(x,z) \log p(z|x)\, dz\,dx \\
   &= -\iint p(x,z)\log\frac{p(x,z)}{p(x)}\,dz\,dx\\
   &= \underbrace{-\iint p(x,z)\log p(x,z)\,dx\,dz}_{\mathbb{H}[X,Z]} + \iint p(x,z) \log p(x) \,dx\,dz \\
   &= \mathbb{H}[X,Z] + \int \log p(x)  \underbrace{\left[\int p(x,z) \,dz\right]}_{p(x)}  dx \\
   &= \mathbb{H}[X,Z] - \underbrace{\left( -\int p(x) \log p(x) \, dx \right)}_{\mathbb{H}[X]}\\ &= \mathbb{H}[X,Z] - \mathbb{H}[X]
   \end{align}
   The discrete analogue is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy).
2. I suppose it is somewhat debatable what makes the most sense. One thing to note is that we are minimizing $D_{\text{KL}}[q(x,z)\mid\mid p(x,z)]$ (or the JS rather), which means that maximizing $\mathcal{I}_q[x,z]$ should also be maximizing $\mathcal{I}_p[x,z]$. So in that sense, perhaps it does not matter (since ideally $p(x,z)$ and $q(x,z)$ should be matched).
   As they note in 5.2, the adversarial losses enforce matching of the joint distributions (term 1 in eq 18; and as term 1 shrinks, term 3 converges to a constant), so by adding the $\beta \mathcal{I}_q[x,z]$ term, we ensure that we are minimizing an upper bound on the reconstruction error.
   Also it's worth recalling from the paper that they say (section 5.1)

   > We propose to palliate mode collapse by maximizing the mutual information between the samples and the code.

   which was written with regards to regularizing the GAN generator. This 
   $\beta \mathcal{I}_q[x,z]$ can be viewed as such as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering and sorry for late responding. Your second point makes great sense to me. But the result of your first derivation is almost the same as mine; you just swap $X$ and $Z$!